# Extjs routing best practices

Tags: extjs, routes

I want to implement viewcontrollers along with routing. I want to know possible best ways/best practices to implement routing in extjs.

Answer (score 1):

To your app directory add a new directory called 'controller' and inside add a new file which extend [Ext.app.Controller](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.app.Controller.html)

Inside the controller you can define a [routes](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.app.Controller.html#cfg-routes) so the app will listen to them.

After you create your controller, In your Application.js add to [controllers](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.app.Application.html#cfg-controllers) property your new controller.

Whenever you will use [redirectTo](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.app.ViewController.html#method-redirectTo) in your viewController it will go to the route listener.

Comment: Thnx for reply.But I want some tips i.e. which are recommended ways      to handle routes in single place.Any complex ex. will help

Comment: It's kinda hard to define it, one place is a good for combine routes on the same types like: #/users/:name, #/users/job/:title so you gather them in users controller. since viewController  is used in many places for specific view I would say it's not a good idea to listen inside it.

Comment: regarding to complex, are you meaning to complex string in the route?

Comment: No i dont want to handle like '#/users/:id', but instead i want to handle in generic way say simply on '#'.Accordingly i will pass any params from which i can decide which controller/view to instantiate(for view controllers approach).
By complex i mean different ways i can handle this thing.